# How to recover backed up GPT disk with DD but without the extra GPT information?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning

A few years ago I backed up my laptop hdd with dd so that I could install linux but then revert back to windows if I wanted to. I didn't know much about UEFI and none about GPT disks, so I didn't do anything other than:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=somefile.bin bs=64K
```

Then I restored it a few days ago and TADA, the FS in the partitions are unidentifiable. In windows' `diskpart` it shows the correct number of partitions with the correct sizes but the FS show as RAW for all of them.

In linux's `gparted` it shows all as Unidentified or something like that.

Is there a way I could perhaps fix this and make my windows partitions bootable again? I mean, I wanted to upgrade it to windows 10. I don't mind losing the data I had on it, but I don't have a recovery disk and the laptop came with Windows 8 so no product key or COA on it. :(

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So what are you asking for exactly?  How to reinstall windows?

Comment: I'm asking how to recover backed up GPT disk with DD but without the extra GPT information

Comment: Define "the extra GPT information".  If the filesystems are not being recognized after restoring, then your backup is corrupt, or you did not backup and restore it correctly.  You mentioned that you don't mind losing the information, which seems to indicate that you are ready to just format the drive and reinstall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `dd` operation backed up the entire disk, including the GPT data structures. Those data structures define the start and end points of partitions, so they're *necessary* to access the data within the partitions. If you restored in the same way (to `/dev/sda`, not to `/dev/sda1` or some other partition), the filesystems stored in the partitions *should* be accessible. Thus, something has gone badly wrong. Four possibilities occur to me:

- **Bad backup** -- You might have backed up in some way other than what you've specified. For instance, you might have backed up a partition (like `/dev/sda1`) rather than a whole disk; or you might have gzipped the backup and forgotten this detail; or you might have used a tool other than `dd`. In this case, you must figure out what you *actually* did in order to recover the data.
- **Bad restore** -- As above, but on the restore side. Obviously, you're closer to this, so you're less likely to be remembering something incorrectly.
- **Data corruption** -- In-between the backup time and now, your backup file might have been damaged in any number of ways. If this has happened, recovery may be difficult or impossible. OTOH, recovery could be as simple as using a filesystem repair tool (you'd need to do this in Windows for NTFS).
- **Differing disk sizes** -- If the original and restore disks differ in size, problems can occur:

  - If your restore disk is smaller than the original, your secondary GPT data structures will not exist on the backup, rendering the partition table technically invalid, although the main partition table would still be accessible. An OS might or might not be able to get past this and access the partitions, but if the size difference is greater than a few sectors, at least one partition is likely to be badly damaged. In this case, your best bet is to restore to a disk that's at least as large as the original.
  - If your restore disk is larger than the original (even by a single sector), the backup GPT data structures won't be where they should be. Most OSes should be able to cope with this, but if you suspect this is an issue, you can use `gdisk` to fix the problem:

    1. Launch `gdisk` on the disk.
    2. Type `x` to enter the experts' menu.
    3. Type `e` to relocate the backup data structures.
    4. Type `w` to save your changes. You'll be asked for verification. Give it.

If you can't figure out what happened and how to correct for that problem, my only suggestion is to use [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) on the restored disk. If you're lucky, TestDisk may be able to work around a damaged partition table, but if the problem is something like your backup being gzipped and you haven't ungzipped it, TestDisk will be useless. Likewise if the filesystem data structures themselves have been damaged.

Comment: I did gzip the backup by piping dd through gzip to the file. I tested the gzip archive and it is ok. I then used gunzip piping it to dd to write to /dev/sda. From my research it seemed like there was special treatment required if the disk was GPT but from what you're saying what I did would have been enough. I'm guessing there is something wrong with the backup file or something went wrong with the restore. What I'll do is to unzip it and try to mount the partitions one by one to eliminate bad backup. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Different logical sector size in the original disk and the new disk maybe (or any enclosure/adapter involved)?

Comment: Well, I didn't replace nor remove the hard drive from the laptop. I'd assume dd would do the work.

Comment: Tom Yan's idea is a good one. If the disk isn't the same one used originally, or if it was moved to or from an external USB enclosure, the logical sector size will have changed, which will mess everything up.

Comment: s/will/may, though that is unlikely.  Virtually all consumer level drives on the market use 512 byte logical sectors even if they have 4k physical sectors to maintain compatibility with Windows ( at least of XP, maybe newer versions properly support 4k native drives ).  Filesystems generally use 4k blocks anyhow and so are usually not bothered by switching between 4k and 512b logical sectors.

Comment: Yes, "may have changed" rather than "will have changed" -- poor word choice on my part. Significant numbers of external disks use 4KiB logical sectors. (In fact, the external enclosures typically do a translation that's the reverse of what most Advanced Format disks do, converting groups of eight 512-byte sectors into individual 4096-byte sectors.) I don't see a mention in the original question of whether the disk(s) involved were internal, external, or a mixture of the two, although an inference of the original being internal is reasonable.

Comment: It's true that most filesystems shouldn't be bothered by a change in the sector size, but the partition table will be, and the problem described could well be caused by such a confusion.